# Script to change Site Collection Owner in SharePoint?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've been tasked to write a PowerShell script that will iterate through all of our MS SharePoint 2013 sites and give us the capability to change the primary site collection owner (on our farm) to who we want it to be. Is this possible? I apologize if it isn't, I'm new to both PowerShell and SharePoint.

Comment: Yes is possible, [start here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx) and try to search with google

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I've been spending the day researching and familiarizing myself with them.

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty so might have a few errors,  but try the below.

```
$username="YourDomainUserName";
foreach($site in Get-SPSite)
{
    $confirmedUsername = $site.RootWeb.EnsureUser($username)
    $site.set_AllowUnsafeUpdates(1)
    $site.Owner = $confirmedUsername
    $site.set_AllowUnsafeUpdates(0)
    Write-Host "User $confirmedUsername is now site collection admin for $site"
}
```

Comment: Nice script. Just in case I would check the value of AllowUnsafeUpdate before changing it because it may be true before running this script.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea,  as i said, it's quick and dirty,  but gives the basics.